# How to refer to a variable in a Firebase server which belongs to a particular document?

Tags: database, variables, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Background: I'm writing an app in which you can store the plus points and fives of a class.

I do this with Flutter and Firebase. My Firestore database collection is called 'mates' and it has several documents, with a unique, auto-ID. Every document has three fields: a name(string), points(number), fives(number).
I have made this far with the help of this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqJ_KjFzL9I&t=591s

I want to modify the GUI a bit, in each listtile I display the name, button for decrementing points, the value of points, button for incrementing points, button for decrementing fives, value of fives, button for incrementing fives and a button for setting the value of fives to zero.

My question would be, that how can I refer to the fields(points, fives) of the database when changing their values?

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document){
    return ListTile(
      title: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: Text(
                document["Name"],
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
              )
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xffddddff)
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Text(
              document['Points'].toString(),
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
              child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_left),
                        iconSize: 30,
                        onPressed: (){
                          setState(() {
                            if(points!=0) { //I mean here
                              points--; //I mean here
                            }
                          });
                        }
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "$points", //I mean here
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 30
                      ),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                        iconSize: 30,
                        onPressed: (){
                          setState(() {
                            points++; //I mean here
                            if(points==10){ //I mean here
                              points=0; //I mean here
                              fives++; //I mean here
                            }
                          });
                        }
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "$fives", //I mean here
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 30
                      ),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.check_circle),
                        iconSize: 30,
                        onPressed: (){
                          setState(() {
                            fives=0; //I mean here
                          });
                        }
                    ),
                  ]
              )
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Punkte++"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection("mates").snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if(!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading...");
            return ListView.builder(
              itemExtent: 80.0,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                _buildListItem(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
                );
              }
          ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I would advise to check the question guidelines to help you improve the chances of receiving quality answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JoãoSoares What's wrong with my question?